# Java- regex matches group - String without spaces

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

i have the following String :

```
{"asdasdasdsd"["$[day()]$"],"asdasd":"$[time()]$","day":"$[day()]$","asdasdasd":["$[random(4,5)]$"]}
```

I want to get the Strings inside my prefix and suffix. 
The problem is that the String does not spaces and so i get only one group:

```
    private String prefix = "\\$\\[";  //$[
    private String suffix = "\\]\\$";  //]$
    private String regexString =  prefix + ".*" + suffix;

    try {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(regexString);
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(json);
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(regexMatcher.start()+ ": " + regexMatcher.group());
            for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(i));
                System.out.println(regexMatcher.start(i));
                System.out.println(regexMatcher.end(i));
            }
        } 
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the output is:

```
17: $[day()]$"],"asdasd":"$[time()]$","day":"$[day()]$","asdasdasd":["$[random(4,5)]$
```

I want the output to be:

```
day()  
time() 
day() 
random(4,5)
```

how can i handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no groups because there's no `(...)` in your pattern.

The `.*` also won't work well, because you want non-greedy matching with `.*?` instead.

Change this:

```
    String regexString =  prefix + ".*" + suffix;
```

To this:

```
    String regexString =  prefix + "(.*?)" + suffix;
```

In any case, it would be better to use a JSON parsing library than regular expressions.